# Bash script programming for inputing text through terminal  and time to a log file

Tags: bash, shell, logging, scripting

Iam new to bash script programming.

I want to implement a bash script `deploymLog`, which accepts as input one string argument(name)

Eg:

```
 [root@localhost Desktop]# ./deploymLog.sh name
```

Here i want to pass the string argument through terminal.

As an  initial step, I need to append the current timestamp along with this input string  to a log file say `Logone.txt`  in current directory in the below format

```
[name]=[System time timestamp1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, I have understand what you want.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    LOGFILE="Logone.txt"

    if [ $# -eq 0 ];then
      echo "Failed, please enter a name" >&2
      exit 1
    fi

    if  [ $# -gt 1 ];then
      echo "Too much arguments" >&2
      exit 1
    fi

    echo "$1=`date +%s`" >> $LOGFILE
```

This small script add a name and system timestamp to a file named `Logone.txt`.

Eg.:

```
$ ./deploymLog Marcel
$ ./deploymLog Jean
$ ./deploymLog Picsou
$ cat Logone.txt
Marcel=1329798949
Jean=1329798956
Picsou=1329798963
```

**EDIT :** This script is for Unix bash and not for batch, I think you want it under windows batch, change your **bash** to **batch** in your description to avoid confusing, and sorry I can't help you, I do not know anything about batch.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

# Check that exactly one argument was given
test $# = 1 || { echo usage: $(basename $0) name; exit 1; } >&2

exec >> Logone.txt                    # redirect output to log file
printf "[%s]=[%s]\n" "$1" "$(date)"   # print [name]=[timestamp]
```